# multiple column group by and sum only two columns

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

searchList.GroupBy(s =>

```
    new { 
    s.ClientRef,
    s.ClientName,
    s.Option, s.WineID, s.Producer, 
    s.Brand, s.Variety, s.Format, s.Vintage,
    s.MaturityTo, s.RPS, s.TradeDate, s.Target, s.AuctionRequested,
    s.UKUpdated, s.GlobalUpdated }) 

.Select(y => new { ClientRef = y.Key.ClientRef,

y.Key.ClientName, y.Key.Option, y.Key.WineID,
y.Key.Producer, y.Key.Brand, y.Key.Variety, y.Key.Format, y.Key.Vintage, 
y.Key.MaturityTo, y.Key.RPS, y.Key.TradeDate, y.Key.Target,
y.Key.AuctionRequested, y.Key.UKUpdated, y.Key.GlobalUpdated,

TotalBottles = y.Sum(z => z.Bottles), 

TotalUnitPrice = y.Sum(z => z.Unit) }).ToList();
```

Hi above is my actual query look like. 
but I want those group by key columns to come from a string[] cols rather then fix. columns could be 3,4 or any number up to 18 and would be sum up during the group by process.

so I want 
**searchList.GroupBy(s=>cols.split(','))
.select(new {cols.split(','), TotalUnit= s.sum(z=>z.Unit),TotalBottles= s.sum(z=>z.Bottles)}).ToList ();**

Comment: Please format your code so that it's human-readable.

Comment: *All* code should be included in code block. Not only to look better, but also for better readability. Does the second line belong to the code?

Comment: I have solved it myself with the help of Dynamic linq and help from various blogs. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Download System.Linq.Dynamic package or use nuget to add it to your project.

Step2:  try to understand the code and use it.

```
               string[] finalColumnList = finalGroupByCols.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);                    
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int counter = 0;
                char com = ',';
                sb.Append("new ( ");
                foreach (string colName in finalColumnList)
                {
                    string right = colName;
                    string left = colName;
                    if (left == "WineID")
                    {
                        sb.Append("Convert.ToInt32(").Append("it[\"").Append(left).Append("\"] ).ToString() as ");

                    }
                    else if (left == "Format" || left == "Vintage" || left == "Bottles" || left == "MaturityTo")
                    {
                        sb.Append("Convert.ToDouble(").Append("it[\"").Append(left).Append("\"] ) as ");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("it[\"").Append(left).Append("\"] as ");
                    }

                    counter++;
                    if (counter == finalColumnList.Length)
                        com = ' ';
                    sb.Append(right).Append(com);
                }
                sb.Append(")");

                var SQLval = CommonLib.DataConverter.ListToDataTableConverter(searchList).AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().GroupBy(sb.ToString(), "it")
                         .Select("new (Sum(Convert.ToDouble(it[\"Bottles\"].ToString())) as TotalBottles, Sum(Convert.ToDouble(it[\"Unit\"].ToString())) as TotalUnit,it.key)").Cast<object>().ToList(); ;
```